# VBA delete duplicate row with no column value(s)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that acts as a log for tracking hospital discharges. This is updated daily and I get duplicate data (if a patient is still in the hospital and hasn't been discharged yet). The rows of the dupes are getting removed, but the wrong dupe is getting deleted.

Columns H-J show whether or not a follow up is scheduled, I do not want this deleted, only the dupe that has no value in columns H-J. I'm struggling to add this condition to my code. Help is most appreciated.

Here's my code and an image of the spreadsheet below:

```
Sub DeDupe()
  Columns("A:J").Select
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$1225").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7), Header:=xlYes
  Range("C8").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like [RemoveDuplicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) doesn't provide any finer control of what rows get removed.

Comment: Agree with @cxw, I fear you will need to write your own "deduper" with a full macro that checks for duplicate (in a dictionary) and whether columns I-J are empty.

Comment: Would there be a better a better way to go about this if I can't modify RemoveDuplicates any further? I was thinking to loop through all rows and delete dupes with the same data in rows A-G, but I'm not sure how to keep the data in H-J to the corresponding row, instead of it shifting down when the dupe rows are removed, if that makes sense .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but works for the test case you provided: Sort, then remove duplicates.

```
Sub DeDupe()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")    ' Always a good idea
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$1225").Sort Header:=xlYes, key1:=ws.Range("A1:A1225"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=ws.Range("H1:H1225"), order2:=xlDescending
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$1225").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7), Header:=xlYes   ' ^ column with blanks ^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ blanks last
End Sub
```

Sorting descending on column H puts the blanks last, at least in Excel 2013 on Windows 8.1 as tested.  Then the RemoveDuplicates keeps the first row and deletes the others, thereby deleting the rows with the blanks.

You may need to add other sort conditions.  If so, first figure out a sort that works.  Then turn on the macro recorder, do that sort, turn off the macro recorder, and paste the recorded sort code in place of the `Sort` line above.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks @cxw!

Comment: @kfire35 Glad to help!  As I think you have just found out, you can only accept one answer.  However, you can upvote both, and it would make sense to do so given that both helped you.  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a bit more about the logistics (and another badge :) ).

Answer (score 1):

This will work on Windows.  If you are using a MAC then either replace the ArrayList with a Collection or buy a Windows PC.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatedWithEmtpyCells()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Long
    Dim key As String
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            key = Join(Array(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, 2), .Cells(x, 3), .Cells(x, 4), .Cells(x, 6), .Cells(x, 7)), "|")
            If list.Contains(key) Then
                If Len(Join(Array(.Cells(x, 8), .Cells(x, 9), .Cells(x, 10)), "")) = 0 Then .Rows(x).Delete
            Else
                list.Add key
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```